# Add responsive Horizontal line after image using css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Want to add horizontal line after image and it should be responsive.Right now it has 5 images in future i can add 6th image dynamically.So lines should be responsive to take 6th image.
Sample Of Image:
[image: Sample Of Image]

```css
    a {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    a:after {
      content: "";
      width: 80%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      height: 1px;
      background: green;
    }
img{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%
}
```

```html
 <a href="">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="error">
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
hr {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="error">
</a>
<hr>

<a href="">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="error">
</a>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you've set the `<a>` tag to `display: block;` which means that it occupies the entire line. This means that the line you've added will be 80% of the available space for the `<a>` tag.

If possible, consider adding an inline wrapper `<div>` and attach your line to that instead.

```css
.link-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.link-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.link-wrapper a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 2em;
}

.link-wrapper img {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="link-wrapper">
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mWMO.png?s=48">
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mWMO.png?s=48">
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mWMO.png?s=48">
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mWMO.png?s=48">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends but something like this could do the job.

```css
.bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bar:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 425px) {
  .bar {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .bar:before {
    width: 1px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: none;
    height: 90%;
  }
  .image-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="Alternative Text">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="Alternative Text">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="Alternative Text">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice example : I am using this in my step by step project

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: @rakeshjaiswal your welcome. Please accept it as answer if it's helpful.

Comment: need different color between images.like border between first and second should be red,second and third should be green.....@mhrabiee

Comment: @rakeshjaiswal what you want to achieve is kinda very depends on UI mockup and not suitable for dynamic content or in responsive implementation because it needs specific width of lines.

Answer (score 0):

to add new line here :

- add a new div
- adjust the `left` property for the elements between start and end to fit all ... I give 2st 30% and 3rd 60% because I have 2 element ... so when you add new on decrease this.
- finally I added background to all from `.tline div` for demo but you can specify a new background to each div

```css
body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}



.tline {
  border-top: 2px solid gray;
  position: relative;
}

.tline div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: px solid;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -25px;
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/bandmember.jpg") center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.tline div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 30%;
}
.tline div:nth-child(3) {
  left: 60%;
}
.tline div:last-child {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tline">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```